# Determine 'valid until' date in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, date, join

In this table I store changeable values for certain spids.
As days go by, these values can change, and an spid can get a new value.

Now I want to find out until when a certain value is enabled.

This is the data for a single spids

```
uid  spid   propertyvalue   creationdate      
--------------------------------------------------
1    3      First name       2010-01-17 22:34:00
37   3      Second name      2010-01-18 01:07:24
38   3      Third name       2010-01-18 01:09:00
39   3      Fourth name      2010-01-18 01:18:16
40   3      Fifth name       2010-01-18 01:20:02
```

So the first value starts at **2010-01-18 01:07:24** and would be valid until **2010-01-18 01:01:00**.

I already tried this query:

```
SELECT s1 . * , 
       s2.creationdate AS datetwo
  FROM salespointproperty s1
  JOIN salespointproperty s2 ON s1.spid = s2.spid
                            AND s1.creationdate < s2.creationdate
```

That gives me a lot of double-records (some of them wrong), and it always leaves out the last new name (as it doesn't have a new creationdate following it)
Example:

```
uid spid    propertyvalue    creationdate           datetwo
-------------------------------------------------------------- 
1   3       First name       2010-01-17 22:34:00    2010-01-18 01:07:24 *
1   3       First name       2010-01-17 22:34:00    2010-01-18 01:09:00
37  3       Second name      2010-01-18 01:07:24    2010-01-18 01:09:00 *
1   3       First name       2010-01-17 22:34:00    2010-01-18 01:18:16
37  3       Second name      2010-01-18 01:07:24    2010-01-18 01:18:16
38  3       Third name       2010-01-18 01:09:00    2010-01-18 01:18:16 *
1   3       First name       2010-01-17 22:34:00    2010-01-18 01:20:02
37  3       Second name      2010-01-18 01:07:24    2010-01-18 01:20:02
38  3       Third name       2010-01-18 01:09:00    2010-01-18 01:20:02
39  3       Fourth name      2010-01-18 01:18:16    2010-01-18 01:20:02 *
```

Only the lines with an asterix are correct. The fifth name is missing.

Comment: That join doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: 1. Your sample data doesn't have uid = 1. Please add that in. 2. In the results, the creationdates of uid 37-39 are the creationdates of 36-38 respectively. Is that right?

Comment: Yes they were, I fixed them now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that in your example, uid 37 is valid until uid 38, uid 38 is valid until uid 39 etc.

```
SELECT
  s1.uid,
  s1.spid,
  s1.propertyvalue,
  s1.creationdate,
  MIN(s2.creationdate) AS datetwo
FROM salespointproperty s1
INNER JOIN salespointproperty s2
    ON s1.spid = s2.spid
    AND s1.creationdate < s2.creationdate
GROUP BY
  s1.uid,
  s1.spid,
  s1.propertyvalue,
  s1.creationdate;
```

Comment: Thank you, that does list only the correct dates. Perfect.
But how do I get the fifht date to appear? (The date which does not have an end date. Or it should be NOW())

Comment: Change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN, change datetwo to `COALESCE(MIN(s2.creationdate), NOW())`.